# Maximize JBoss 7.1 server log history file count

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-logging

I use jboss logging and i have this handler:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
   <formatter>
     <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
   </formatter>
   <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
   <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
   <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

How can i set that jboss delete the old log files (e.g. that are older than 30 days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do from the handler configuration. You'd have to setup some kind of cron job to delete older files.